# Merge Sort code throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, mergesort

I did a very simple merge sort implementation but I keep on getting java.lang.NullPointerException. Here's my code :

```
public class MergeSort {

    private int[] c;
    private int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    public MergeSort(int[] a, int[] b){

        while( i < a.length && j < b.length){

            if(a[i] > b[j])
                c[k++] = b[j++];
            else
                c[k++] = a[i++];
        }

        while(i < a.length){
            c[k++] = a[i++];
        }

        while(j < b.length){
            c[k++] = b[j++];
        }

        i = 0;
        while(i < c.length){
            System.out.print(c[i++] + " ");
        }
    }

}
```

And I am calling the constructor from the main class like this:

```
public class MainRun {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Merge Sort Algorithm");

        int a[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
        int b[] = {2, 6, 7, 9, 11};

        new MergeSort(a, b);

    }

}
```

While I know I get the exception for using uninitialized objects, still I am unable to find the error in my code. Here's the exact error:

> Merge Sort Algorithm Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at MergeSort.(MergeSort.java:14)
>     at MainRun.main(MainRun.java:11)

What am I doing wrong? Thanks :)

Comment: You didn't initialized the `c` variable

Comment: You should also reconsider your design.

Comment: provide full logcat stack trace.

Comment: @ArmaanStranger not really needed...

Comment: @SeniorJD Should I initialize it with zeroes? Is it a good practice?

Comment: Yes, it is a default practice ;) for primitive types such as `int, double` the array will fill with zeros, for user types like `String` it will fill with nulls and it is OK.

Comment: @SeniorJD I think Philipp Sander should get it for providing a complete answer :D

Comment: @PhilippSander Right. Well Answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`c` is not initialized

you do this by writing:

```
private int[] c = new int[x];
```

this creates an array with the length `x` filled with zeros

Comment: Suppose I don't know the array length, what do I do then? pass a arbitrary large range?

Comment: That's a design issue, but for a merge sort you surely do know the size of the array - it will be the size of the original input array.

Answer (score 1):

You have failed to initalise the variable `c`, so it is still `null` when you tried to access it on the line:

```
c[k++] = b[j++];
```

The solution is to create a new array like so:

```
c = new int[x];
```

Where `x` is the intended size of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You neet to initialize the array `c` with required length.

```
private int[] c = new int[length];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized your `c` array, its only declared:

```
private int[] c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just init the `c`:

```
public class MergeSort {

    private int[] c;
    private int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    public MergeSort(int[] a, int[] b){
        c = new int[a.length]; // <- this is what you need

        while( i < a.length && j < b.length){

            if(a[i] > b[j])
                c[k++] = b[j++];
            else
                c[k++] = a[i++];
        }

        while(i < a.length){
            c[k++] = a[i++];
        }

        while(j < b.length){
            c[k++] = b[j++];
        }

        i = 0;
        while(i < c.length){
            System.out.print(c[i++] + " ");
        }
    }

}

public class MainRun {


   public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Merge Sort Algorithm");

        int a[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
        int b[] = {2, 6, 7, 9, 11};

        new MergeSort(a, b);

    }

}
```